# Python - pass value back to main() based on when a button is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Forgive me if this is a badly mangled way of doing things, but I'm new to development in general.

I am trying to create a window with a number of buttons using tkinter, each button having the name of a player on it using a class called from main().

I then want to be able to use the name on the button that is pressed later in the app, so I want to pass that back to main().  So, if I click on the Annie button, I want to open up a new window later called 'Options for Annie' and I'm assuming that the value 'Annie' needs to be passed back to the main function.

My main code:

```
<imports appear here>
def main():

    players = ['Annie','Benny','Carrie','Donny']
    winHome = playerWindow(root,players)
    print("In main() : " + winHome.selected)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My class code:

```
<imports appear here>
root=Tk()

class playerWindow():

def selectPlayer(self,selname):

    self.selected = selname
    print("In class: " + self.selected)

def __init__(self, master, players=[]):

    colours = ['red','green','orange','white','yellow','blue']
    self.selected = ""

    r = 0
    for p in players:
        randcol = random.randint(0,len(colours))-1
        if colours[randcol] in ('blue','green'):
            fgcol='white'
        else:
            fgcol='black'
        playername = delplayer = p
         playername = Button(root, text=playername, bg=colours[randcol], fg=fgcol, width=15, command=lambda name = playername:self.selectPlayer(name)).grid(row=r,column=0)
        s = ttk.Separator(root, orient=VERTICAL)
        delplayer = Button(root, text='Del', bg='grey', fg='red', width=5, command=lambda name = delplayer: print("Delete Player %s" % name)).grid(row=r,column=1)
        r = r + 1

    Button(root, text="New Player", fg="black", command=lambda: print("New Player Functionality"), width=15).grid(row = len(players)+3,column=0)
    Button(root, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.destroy, width=15).grid(row = len(players)+3,column=1)
```

What is happening is that the window gets created, the next line in main() is run (my added print statement) which is empty, obviously as main is continuing.  When I press the button, the sleectPlayer function is called and works.

Somehow I need to get the value back to main() to go on to the next task using that value, however I don't seem to be able to frame the question correctly to get the answers I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Python 3.5.1

Comment: Your indentation is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already accessing it. I personally don't like returning to the main function, instead I suggest creating a top-level class to link back to. This should help make things flow better.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import random

class PlayerWindow():
    def __init__(self, master, parent, players=[]):

        self._parent = parent

        colours = ['red','green','orange','white','yellow','blue']
        self.selected = ""

        r = 0
        for p in players:
            randcol = random.randint(0,len(colours))-1
            if colours[randcol] in ('blue','green'):
                fgcol='white'
            else:
                fgcol='black'
            playername = delplayer = p
            playername = tk.Button(master, text=playername, bg=colours[randcol], \
                        fg=fgcol, width=15, command=lambda name = \
                        playername:self.selectPlayer(name)).grid(row=r,column=0)

            s = ttk.Separator(master, orient=tk.VERTICAL)

            delplayer = tk.Button(master, text='Del', bg='grey', fg='red', \
                        width=5, command=lambda name = delplayer: \
                        print("Delete Player %s" % name)).grid(row=r,column=1)
            r = r + 1

        tk.Button(master, text="New Player", fg="black", command=lambda: \
                  print("New Player Functionality"), width=15).\
                  grid(row = len(players)+3,column=0)

        tk.Button(master, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self._parent.close,
                  width=15).grid(row = len(players)+3,column=1)

    def selectPlayer(self, selname):
        self.selected = selname
        print("In class: " + self.selected)
        self._parent.hello() # call hello function of top-level, links back

class MyApplication(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self._master = master
        players = ['Annie','Benny','Carrie','Donny']
        self._player_window = PlayerWindow(master, self, players)
        print("In main() : " + self._player_window.selected)

    def hello(self):
        name = self._player_window.selected
        print("Hello, %s" % name)

    def close(self):
        # any other clean-up
        self._master.destroy()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that!  That's moved me forward a great deal.